# Angular velocities in moving reference frames

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, angular-velocity

Please refer the image below for a clear idea of my question.

[image]

So, the instructor has written the angular velocity of the wheel, w.r.t. ground and the unit vectors he used are the ones for the frame B. I can convert the angular velocity (which are currently in terms of unit vectors of frame B ie, i,j,k) in terms of the unit vectors for the ground frame (I,J,K).

It seems pretty logical, write i,j,k in terms of I,J,K and then substitute. But my question is what if i go the reverse way around? Can I, according to the figure, say that the net angular velocity of the wheel in terms of unit vectors of ground frame is

ω = ω1(I) +  ω2(J)

and then write I and J in terms of i and j and substitute?
It is evident that i'll get a different result this time! So will I be incorrect if I choose to start writing the expression for  ω in ground frame first and then proceeding to write it in the frame B or is there some silly mistake I am making in the process?

Thanks!